# Comparing Eevee & Unreal as render engines in animated film

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, unreal-engine

I've followed the use of Unreal as the render endpoint in animated film for some time – specifically, Epic's use of it themselves in their cinematic trailer in 2017:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LS0VsMMTaQA&list=PLBNTbstFRU1HNFcnbKJ59rhp-S-xslUqI&index=2&t=2862s

Other indie filmmakers have also used Unreal this way, eg.:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8ZMQgyMTk4&list=PLBNTbstFRU1HNFcnbKJ59rhp-S-xslUqI&index=4&t=11s

While Unreal is capable of producing obvious quality:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fC20NWhx4s

... Eevee is also capable of some great stuff too:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BiWmB8mwP70&list=PLBNTbstFRU1HNFcnbKJ59rhp-S-xslUqI&index=24&t=0s

**So..., can someone explain to me how Unreal's render engine differs from Eeevee in render quality and speed?**

- Are they different technologies?
- Is one faster than the other?
- Does one produce different quality than the other?

(I'm curious about this because if Unreal produces very similar-quality output in the same amount of time, the advantage would be to keep everything in Blender, obviously, to avoid the work involved in shuffling everything off to another application just to do rendering. If, however, Unreal offers great advantages, the work would be justified.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective question and too broad for a stack exchange post in my opinion. But my take on this would be to use whatever you are used to. Unreal tools are geared toward real time but Blender have it all in one software (from modeling to rendering). With proper skills and time you can achieve great results in both Eevee and Unreal. The technologies are similar if not exactly the same for most tools. In short if I had to make an animation I'd use Blender, but if I needed interactivity (a game) I'd go for Unreal. Most 3D artist familiar with Blender would do the same but I could totally see someone more familiar with Unreal modeling in Blender and doing everything else in Unreal.

Comment: I'm used to working in both, Arthur, but haven't used Unreal for rendering. I was curious how they differ technically, but also whether one offered any advantage over the other in quality or speed. This isn't a subjective question: The differences should be objectively measurable. I was simply wondering whether anyone has ever done... the measuring.Thanks for responding.

Comment: I understand, it's just that measuring the speed of a scene depends on the scene itself. So without saying what you are going to render exactly you won't get an objective answer but most likely only speculations. It's an interesting topic nonetheless.